# overriding a jquery ui widget string option with an object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-widgets

I want to have a jquery ui widget option be a string by default, but I want it to be able to overridden by an object. When I do this, I actually get the string converted to an object in some strange way, and then extended with whatever object I pass in.

```
$.widget("ui.test", {

    options: {
        anOption: "a,b,c"
    },

    _create: function() {
        console.log(this.options);
    }

});

$('div').test({
    anOption: {
        a: 'A'
    }
});
```

If I skip passing in the option to the widget, it will be received as a string in the _create method. If I pass in an object, the strange behavior occurrs. In chromes js console log I get this, which is not what I want.

```
Object
anOption: Object
0: "a"
1: ","
2: "b"
3: ","
4: "c"
a: "A"
```

How do I solve this?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MatteS75/s9wK2/

Comment: It is converting the string to an object with each character becoming a property based on its index. What do you want it to produce? Over write `anOption` like this `anOption: { a: "A" }`

Comment: It looks like the widget options functionality works like this. `var s = "a string"; console.log($.extend({}, s, {a: "new"}));​`

Comment: I also encoutered this problem in the jquery ui itself, namely the resizable widget: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028342/jquery-ui-resizable-custom-handle-error/13036650

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that has been fixed very recently:

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8713

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/9b908878ae3a9c0fbbd9958b579f223a648c5c69

Answer (score 1):

If you change the option after the widget is created, it will overwrite the option with the object that you want. Is this acceptable?

```
$.widget("ui.test", {

    options: {
        anOption: "a string"
    },

    _create: function() {
        console.log(this.options.anOption);
    }

});

$('div').test({});


$('div').test("option", "anOption", {
    a: "option1",
    b: "option2"
});

var anOption = $('div').test("option", "anOption");

​console.log(anOption);​
```

Comment: I cant accept this solution, although thanks for giving me a possible workaround for now. Thing is, I cant control how other developers are using this widget, and would prefer being able to actually have all options work at first initialization.

Comment: Understood. I figured that I would post a possible way around it. Thanks for getting back to me with an explanation! I think that is good feedback!