# jQueryUI - custom handle not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, resize

I know there's a few questions on this, but from what I can see I am doing it correctly. Alas, no joy.

```
//create and append custom resize (SE) handle
asset.append($('<button />', {text: 'L'}).addClass('ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se'));

//give asset resizability
asset.resizable({handles: {se: '.ui-resizable-se'}, aspectRatio: true});
```

There are no errors, and the handle correctly appears, with the two classes. It's just the drag doesn't happen...

I have had drag working, but only when I allow jQueryUI to generate the handle for me, not with a custom handle.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028342/jquery-ui-resizable-custom-handle-error) mentioned a bug with custom handles that was recently fixed, but I'm on the latest version (1.10.3) so not sure what's up.

What's not to like? If nothing obvious, I'll set up a Fiddle to demo.

Thanks in advance